# r.series - no output 'ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.!

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin

Using grass tool 'r.series' (average of 2 raster files) with QGIS 2.18.28 works correctly. If I use this tool in QGIS 3.4.4 I get an error message:

> Processing algorithm…
>   Algorithm 'r.series' starting…
>   Input parameters:
>   { '-n' : False, 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '', 'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '', 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'input' : ['C:/temp/Raster1.tif','C:/temp/Raster2.tif'], 'method' : [0], 'output' : 'C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_618d89e6582c4df6bf31a66282de5b94/680d6bb22b2f4433a9f1c16faa65163a/output.tif', 'quantile' : '', 'range' : [0,0], 'weights' : '' }

```
g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
r.external input="C:\temp\Raster1.tif" band=1 output="rast_5c53fef7e75ac4" --overwrite -o
r.external input="C:\temp\Raster2.tif" band=1 output="rast_5c53fef7e75ac5" --overwrite -o
g.region n=5740005.091 s=5734489.7695 e=646558.1389 w=640036.9643 res=4.99897995049501
r.series input=rast_5c53fef7e75ac4,rast_5c53fef7e75ac5 method="average" range="0,0" output=outputa1488afaf51e44ffb0265b0eda47ed94 --overwrite
g.region raster=outputa1488afaf51e44ffb0265b0eda47ed94
r.out.gdal -t -m input="outputa1488afaf51e44ffb0265b0eda47ed94" output="C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_618d89e6582c4df6bf31a66282de5b94\680d6bb22b2f4433a9f1c16faa65163a\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNUNG: Sperren gleichzeitiger Zugriffe auf ein Mapset ist unter Windows nicht möglich.
Executing <C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_618d89e6582c4df6bf31a66282de5b94\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
Die Standard Region wurde auf die neue Projektion aktualisiert. Wenn Sie aber mehrere Mapsets haben, sollten Sie `g.region -d` in jedem ausführen, um die Einstellungen von der Standardregion zu übernehmen.
Projektionsinformationen aktualisiert
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.external input="C:\temp\Raster1.tif" band=1 output="rast_5c53fef7e75ac4" --overwrite -o
Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion.
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5c53fef7e75ac4> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.external input="C:\temp\Raster2.tif" band=1 output="rast_5c53fef7e75ac5" --overwrite -o
Übersteuere die Überprüfung der Projektion.
Reading band 1 of 1...
Link to raster map <rast_5c53fef7e75ac5> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region n=5740005.091 s=5734489.7695 e=646558.1389 w=640036.9643 res=4.99897995049501
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.series input=rast_5c53fef7e75ac4,rast_5c53fef7e75ac5 method="average" range="0,0" output=outputa1488afaf51e44ffb0265b0eda47ed94 --overwrite
0..3..6..9..12..15..18..21..24..27..30..33..36..39..42..45..48..51..54..57..60..63..66..69..72..75..78..81..84..87..90..93..96..99..100
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region raster=outputa1488afaf51e44ffb0265b0eda47ed94
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>r.out.gdal -t -m input="outputa1488afaf51e44ffb0265b0eda47ed94" output="C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_618d89e6582c4df6bf31a66282de5b94\680d6bb22b2f4433a9f1c16faa65163a\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
ERROR 6: SetColorTable() only supported for Byte or UInt16 bands in TIFF format.
Checking GDAL data type and nodata value...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Using GDAL data type <Float64>
Die Eingabe-Rasterkarte enthält Zellen mit dem NULL-Wert (no-data). Der Wert -1.#IND wird verwendet, um NoData-Werte in der Eingabekarte zu kennzeichnen. Sie können NoData-Wert mit dem Parameter nodata bestimmen.
Exporting raster data to GTiff format...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
r.out.gdal komplett. File <C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_618d89e6582c4df6bf31a66282de5b94\680d6bb22b2f4433a9f1c16faa65163a\output.tif> created.
C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_618d89e6582c4df6bf31a66282de5b94\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up temporary files...
Execution completed in 3.13 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_618d89e6582c4df6bf31a66282de5b94/680d6bb22b2f4433a9f1c16faa65163a/output.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'r.series' finished
```

Can anyone reproduce this issue?

Comment: The color table can't be written in a GeoTIFF file if it has not Byte or UInt16 format for the pixel values. But you don't need a color table if you are not working with pixel values as colours. `r.series` command works fine, is `r.gdal.out` command in the _r.series_ algorithm wich tell that error. Your output is well generated?

Comment: There is no output...that is the issue. I don't care about the colour table.

Comment: Can you edit your question adding the complete log output? (as preformatted text )

Answer (score 2):

The command says that the output is there: 
`C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_618d89e6582c4df6bf31a66282de5b94\680d6bb22b2f4433a9f1c16faa65163a\output.tif`

and loaded to the canvas:
`Loading resulting layers`
`Algorithm 'r.series' finished`

Don't worry about the color table error, that's not the problem.

It's possible that the output will be a raster without data, because the range to average is from 0 to 0. It's also possible that 0 to 0 should mean **no range**.  Consider it a bug in the algorithm and report it.

Meanwhile, if you want a raster output with values, set a range within which the input values should be taken into account for the calculation of the average.